# Convolution that uniquely identifies all possible spatial patterns

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, convolution

I'm working on a problem that requires searching for some unique 3x3 patterns in binary images. My current method is to do a convolution with a kernel where each value is a different power of two, essentially producing a 9-bit number for each pixel. This is working for me, and I can search for my patterns quickly by simply checking for the corresponding numbers.

I have a couple questions:

1. Is there a name for this kernel or method? I cannot find any
   reference to one like it, but I don't exactly know what to call it.
2. Is there another way to go about this? I get skeptical of my methods when I don't see anyone else doing it :)

Comment: There are some common operations built on this. Typically this is followed by a lookup table. In your case, the lookup table would have a value of 1 for the 9-bit numbers corresponding to the patterns you are looking for, and 0 for the other table entries. See for example [the `bwlookup` function in MATLAB's Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlookup.html).

Comment: what's the _goal_ of all this? you seem to require some local "feature descriptor"... SIFT would be a rather complex one, and "local binary patterns" is a simpler one, though what you have seems even simpler.